# how can i add a camera marker without name with python?

Tags: timeline, marker

I'm trying to add a camera marker with an empty name

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
scene.timeline_markers.new('', frame=scene.frame_current)
```

while this works, it only works if the name of the scene is "Scene" if the name is something else it won't work.
how can i make it so that it works on the current scene regardless of name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could access [using the context](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.1/info_quickstart.html#context) instead of a name...

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.timeline_markers.new('', frame=scene.frame_current)
```

Comment: ah, thank you! this worked